# Cross- domain tracking: the Ga linker parameter don't appears in the URL

Tags: parameters, google-analytics, cross-domain, google-tag-manager, clientid

I have been setting cross domain tracking via the instruction and ensure all required steps below:

- All domains included in cross-domain tracking must collect data to the same Google Analytics Property
- Both domain in the Referral Exclusion List
- Use allowLinker= TRUE & cookie domain= auto, add both domains in cross domain setting in Google tag manager.
  **But the Ga linker parameter doesn't appear in the target URL.I mean this appears but it disappears when page loaded.** and all the conversions related to target domain keep showing from direct source instead of paid search.
  *Ex: my source page is cafe24.vn and my target page is the sign up form which is user.cafe24.com/vn*.
  We also have another branch that uses cross domain tracking for user.cafe24.com with a subfolder is user.cafe24.com/ph. Does this affect?
  I don't know where to find the problems. If you guys know, please help!
  Note: I also have been change the GTM cross domain to user.cafe24.com instead of cafe24.com but it's still not working!
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIxw9.png)

Comment: 0

"I mean this appears but it disappears when page loaded." - it's a normal, ga parameter must be shown once only - just after link. Are you sure that version of GTM container is published? Did you wait 24 hours?

Comment: @zborovskaya i mean The target domain has the _ga linker parameter in the url but only for one or two seconds.
i test on Google tag assistant and the tag of cross domain fire. I have been setting these for weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration is right, **the problem is that you have a redirect** from the page of the link and the effective page.

Example:

- You are on https://cafe24.vn/
- Then you click on call to to action to go to this link (that contains parameter you want): https://user.cafe24.com/vn/?_ga=2.209319701.771107389.1605275670-2091896452.1605227670
- However **the page is not loaded**, but rather **redirects** to https://user.cafe24.com/vn/join/?action=joinForm&pcMallSkinId=&mobileMallSkinId=

**The parameter is lost** and the cross-domain cannot work.

So, the **solution** is remove the redirect or make sure that the parameter is kept even after the redirect.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Fix the redirect can be done only by developer, right?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Also kept parameters after redirect.

Comment: I am really appreciate your help!

Comment: You're welcome, mark the answer as solved and useful, pls :)